# Android pause Thread instead of remove and stop

Tags: java, android

This simple `Runnable` which i can `postDelay` to start and `removeCallbacks` to stop. But I don't like that.

I want to pause `handler` instead of stop by `removeCallbacks` and then start again to resume paused handler like with play/pause music. Is it possible?

```
/* START */ 
protected final Runnable mUpdateUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        displayData();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateUI, 5000);
    }
};

/* STOP */
customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
```

or other solution to play and pause thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this because pause like pause in music isn't available:

```
public class LooperThread extends Thread {

    private Handler mHandler;

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        synchronized (this) {
            mHandler = new Handler() {
               displayData();
            };
            notifyAll();
        }

        Looper.loop();
    }

    public synchronized Handler getHandler() {
        while (mHandler == null) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //Ignore and try again.
            }
        }
        return mHandler;
    }
}
```